# how i can retrieve from ini [odbc] for connect my app

Tags: mysql, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, teamsql

i have some issue How i can retrieve config.ini--->[odbc] database connection into my getconnection class ? i'm using mysql database
i storage the connection into my database and Config.ini--[odbc] is fine
but when i want to retrive and connect my database into application trow config.ini i can't

check this is my database class :

```
public class DB(
public static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/resturno?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
    public static String user = "root";
    public static String paw = "";

    public static Connection getConnection() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, paw);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("couldn't connect!");
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
)
```

and this is my Config.ini :

```
[ODBC]
ServerName = jdbc:mysql://localhost
DataBase = resturno?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
Username = root
Password = 
Year = 2019
```

and this is my readIni class :

```
public void readIni() {

        try {
            File file = new File(pathIni);
            if (file.exists()) {
                Wini wini = new Wini(new File(pathIni));
                String url = wini.get("ODBC", "ServerName");
                String dbnm = wini.get("ODBC", "DataBase");
                String dbus = wini.get("ODBC", "Username");
                String dbpas = wini.get("ODBC", "Password");
                String dbyer = wini.get("ODBC", "Year");
                if ((url != null && !url.equals("")) && (dbnm != null && !dbnm.equals("")) && (dbus != null && !dbus.equals("")) && (dbpas != null && !dbpas.equals("")) && (dbyer != null && !dbyer.equals(""))) {
                    Serverurl.setText(url);
                    dbname.setText(dbnm);
                    dbuser.setText(dbus);
                    dbpass.setText(dbpas);
                    dbyear.setText(dbyer);

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
    }
```

if you have anything missing i'll help me on my code

Comment: Do you get any Error Message or what exactly does not work?

Comment: no there is no error my question is how to link my config.ini --> [odbc] to my get connection class

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the port of your Database.

```
public static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:<PORT>/resturno?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
```

Usually the port is 3306. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Dear @Malte Thank you for quick answer is working fine with my my code but my quesition is how to link my config.ini --> [odbc] to my getconnection class ?